# How to get some char separated by spaces

Tags: c++, separator

I want to get this character in 3 part: ab,83,and de. But i don't know how to get the char between the spaces and 2 char after the last space. Please tell me how to do it. Thank you

```
void main()
{
    char input[12]="ab 83 de";
    char *p;
    p = strtok(input,"  ");

      while (p != NULL)
      {
        printf ("%s\n",p);
        p = strtok (NULL, "  ");
      }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Comment: why are there two spaces in the argument to `strtok`?

Comment: Your code outputs: `ab` (newline) `83` (newline) `de` (newline) http://ideone.com/lWLqqJ is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Please explain exactly what output you expected (and how this differs from the actual output)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) with `operator>>`:

```
istringstream iss("ab 83 de");
string str;
while (iss >> str) {
    // process with str
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/XZM81126)